# Allow access of Account related records for Community users based on checkbox

Tags: sharing, customer-community, community

I have an object **Sample__c** that looks up to **Account** object. The object has a field **View__c** (checkbox).

I also have a community and users have access to **Account** object and a **Sample__c** related list. I want to only show related **Sample__c** records of its **View__c** is checked. The community users have a profile of **Community User** under the user license **Customer Community**.

I tried making a ***sharing setting*** for the **View__c** object but I have a problem since I can't target the users via ***role***. I tried to add a role to a user with the Community User profile but it is disabled. I also tried making a public group for the sharing setting but the users under the **Community User** profile are not visible and can't be added.

1. How do I only show related **Sample__c** records related to the **Account** if its **Sample__c.View__c** is checked?
2. What can't I add roles to my user with **Community User** profile which is under **Customer Community** license?